# Dialog is not shown properly on some android devices

Tags: android, dialog

It seems on random devices for example Xiaomi redmi note 6 PRO and Samsung Galaxy S20, instead of showing a Dialog, only white column appears:

[image]

Declaration

```
private lateinit var addCardDialog: Dialog
```

Constructor

```
addCardDialog = Dialog(this)
```

I have Following code for showing the dialog

```
    runOnUiThread {
        addCardDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_card)
        addCardDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        addCardDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)



        addCardDialog.addButton.setOnClickListener {
            val cardNumber = addCardDialog.cardNumberEditText.text.toString()
            val cardName = addCardDialog.cardNameEditText.text.toString()

            if (cardNumber.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.insert_card_empty_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else if (!CardUtils.isCardValid(cardNumber) && AppSettings.CHECK_CARD_PAN) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.insert_card_invalid_number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {

                addCardDialog.dismiss()

                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                viewModel.cardName = cardName
                viewModel.getCardByPan(cardNumber)
            }
        }

        addCardDialog.cancelButton.setOnClickListener {
            addCardDialog.dismiss()
        }

        if(!(this as Activity).isFinishing()) {
            addCardDialog.show()
        }
    }
```

The View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paidText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/add_your_card"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cardNumberEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cardNumberEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_frame_drawable"
            android:hint="@string/card_number"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorGrayLight"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cardNameEditText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paidText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cardNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_frame_drawable"
            android:hint="@string/card_name"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorGrayLight"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardNumberEditText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_ripple_blue"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSoWhite"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardNameEditText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_ripple_blue"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSoWhite"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addButton" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Do you have any idea what is the cause?
Do you have any idea what is the cause?
Do you have any idea what is the cause?

Comment: show `dialog_add_card`

Comment: dialog_add_card code added

Comment: I thought that you use `ConstraintLayout`. I had similar issue. Use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout for test case.